# How to remove Margin from edit Text

Tags: android, android-layout

As you can see on below image, edit text is having some margin, i want to remove it.

```
 <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageview_user_image_1"
        android:layout_width="23dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/smile"/>
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/login_user_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_user_image_1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="#808080"
        android:hint="@string/userid"/>
![problem image][1]
```

[image]
[image: target image]

Comment: did you try adding `android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"`, `android:layout_marginRight="0dp"`, `android:layout_marginTop="0dp"`, `android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"` ?

Comment: yeah but its not what exactly i want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageview_user_image_1"
    android:layout_width="23dp"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"

    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@drawable/smile"/>
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/login_user_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_user_image_1"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="#808080"
    android:hint="@string/userid"/>
```

add android:background="@android:color/**transparent**" in edittext

Answer (score 0):

As per Mario Stoilov Said, try this code

```
 <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageview_user_image_1"
    android:layout_width="23dp"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@drawable/home_icon"/>
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/login_user_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_user_image_1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="#808080"
    android:hint="hi"/>
```

by Changing to this `android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"` hope this helps you.

Comment: removing margin from left is not my solution... actually edit field is taking margin from bottom (on real device). so how can i find the answer...